# Why non-volatile approach works?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile, java-memory-model

Look at this code.

Thread:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        read();
    }

    public void write(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public void read() {
        System.out.println(a + " " + b);
    }


}
```

And the main class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        MyThread t = new MyThread();
        t.start();
        t.write(1, 2);
        System.out.println(t.getA() + " " + t.getB());

    }
}
```

Output is:

```
1 2
1 2
```

But as you can see `a` and `b` are not volatile. So why output is not:

```
1 2
0 0
```

And how main thread cache knows about another thread cache without volatile statement? 
Could you show me the example, where that case gives us different values?

Comment: `volatile` is a guarantee. The lack of `volatile` is the lack of a guarantee.

Comment: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#volatile

Comment: Using volatile ensures that your values don't get optimized away.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Why don't you make that an answer so it can be upvoted and accepted? I seems better than the answer I was going to write ;-)

Comment: "I walked across the street without looking both ways and nothing terrible happened. Why didn't I get hit by a car?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing a variable in one thread, and reading it in another thread (without it being volatile, or synchronized etc) is not thread-safe.

You can get either "0 0", "1 0", "0 2", or "1 2" as possible outputs. Neither one of them is guaranteed. A thread *may* cache the values of `a` and `b` which would cause "0 0" to be output, but this is just one possible outcome. It doesn't need to happen.

Volatile would provide the guarantee that "1 2" would be output.

Comment: There is no synchronization between the `write` and `read` methods, so they may not see `1 2` because of that as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one Thread, there won't be a problem anyway. Just have n Threads and log, whatever you can (or better write some Tests). There may be situtations, when it fails.

Ah! Your Integers should be in another class then. Lets say, about 10 Threads modify/read the very same instance. Were are nearly there :D

You will make em volatile then, that's a promise!